# Using $in operator on Cassandra table via stargate API

Tags: database, cassandra, datastax, cql, stargate-oss

I have a Cassandra table and it contains a column named 'marks'. It is not part of the primary key.

Now, I wish to run something like this: **select * from mytable WHERE marks in (58,88);**

How to achieve this? I want to run the same via Stargate API also. I have tried to disable paging but not work. SAI and SASI index does not seem to help. Here is the Stargate URL I am trying to run. The DB asks me to ALLOW FILTERING

http://localhost:8082/v2/keyspaces/mykeyspace/mytable?where={"marks":{"$in":[58,88]}}

Comment: Would you mind posting the output of running `DESC TABLE mykeyspace.mytable;` from the Astra DB UI -> CQL Console screen?

Comment: IF you're not using Astra DB, what's the version of Cassandra you're running? Plus, what version of Stargate are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If `marks` column is not part of the table's primary key, you [cannot](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-serverless/docs/develop/dev-with-rest.html) use in the where clause directly like that in the REST API.

Instead, you would create an index (via the same CQL Console screen/tab) using,

```
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX mykeyspace_mytable_marks_idx ON mykeyspace.mytable(marks) USING 'StorageAttachedIndex';
```

Tips: The `WHERE` clause can be used with other valid search terms: `$eq`, `$in`, `$lt`, `$lte`, `$gt`, `$gte`, `$ne`, and `$exists`, if applicable.

Bonus References:

- [Working with Indexes](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/astra/docs/developing/indexing/sai/sai-create.html)
- [Postman collection of all APIs (gRPC, REST, GraphQL, and Document)](https://www.postman.com/datastax/workspace/stargate-cassandra/overview)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Let's say everything is in place, I want to run a "select *" query via stargate. How would I do that?

Comment: I've already linked two references above that showcases exactly how to achieve that but, here is [a direct read data link](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-serverless/docs/develop/dev-with-rest.html#_read_data) if that helps